# impish security release error on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS while running sudo apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, 22.04

I am getting the following error message while running sudo apt update on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

```
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This is the contents of my  /etc/apt/sources.list file

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.


deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
 #deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

I am somewhat new to Ubuntu and have so far tried every solution I could find on the internet. But still I am not able to fix this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wy do you have an impish repository (Ubuntu 21.10)  in your Jammy/22,04 sources.list ? You have to delete it, both because mixed-version repositories r bound for disaster,  and because impish is EOL and the repo's been removed.

Comment: There are indications that this issue may be commonly occurring in Ubuntu 22.04 ('impish-security' is referenced in the 'Other Software' list). I've posted a GUI-centric answer addressing the same underlying issue at: [Software Updater says "Failed to download repository information" despite working Internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/a/1448787/11522).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that some old repositories from 21.10 are still on the list, even after you've upgraded.

`/etc/apt/sources.list` is only one of the lists that apt-get uses.
In order to see if there are other lists that contain any `impish` repository, run this on a terminal;

```
grep -nvr "^#" /etc/apt/ | grep impish
```

If this command outputs anything, comment out by adding `#` at the beginning of those lines, or delete the whole line. Where these lines are will be given at the beginning of the output at every line.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my issue. There was some other file named impish security release and removing it fixed my issue. Thanks again.

Comment: I had this issue on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 on a brand new hard drive. I wonder what impish security releases are doing in my sources list. If anybody knows why, please let me know. 

Thanks.

Comment: Hey where are the lines which I am supposed to comment out? Will they be in /etc/apt/sources.list.Posting half of the output
grep: /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg: binary file matches
grep: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg~: binary file matches
grep: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/winehq.gpg: binary file matches
grep: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/slack.gpg: binary file matches
grep: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-chrome.gpg: binary file matches
grep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list:1:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem. solved it by remove all character before ".archive"
like this:

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

--->

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I faced the same problem. Based on the accepted answer I ran the below command

```
grep -nvr "^#" /etc/apt/ | grep impish
```

The output shows below files contains `impish` repository.

1. `/etc/apt/sources.list.save`
2. `/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade`
3. `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list`

Since the two first files uses for backup purposes (As I understand), by only commenting in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list` file, The problem have been solved for me.