# Software Updater says "Failed to download repository information" despite working Internet connection

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, update-manager

Running 22.04 on a MacBook Air and all is fine and dandy, but for one tiny quirk. On a daily basis I engage the "Software Updater" application and always get the application response, "Failed to download repository information check your internet connection." In actuality, repository information IS downloaded and ready to install and I proceed with the installation. I am an unsophisticated user and do not know where the Software Updater application goes to find information. All I know is that nearly every day I do get something to install or update. The amazing coders in Ubuntu-Land have even sorted an issue with my internet connection dropping and then picking up again, via assorted recent updates.

The question is, why does "Failed to download repository information" **always** display, even when there is something to download or install?

Comment: There is a failure but the message is misleading. It shows up whenever a repository, likely a PPA, nio longer exists or has no content for your release. Please check your software sources.

Comment: Don't *describe* a problem that you see in the terminal. Descriptions tend to be too vague to be answerable. Copy the actual, complete input and output from the terminal and paste it into your Question above.

Comment: Dear @user535733: Bradburn is refering to the Software Updater U.I.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I do not know what a PPA is. My software source is whatever is on the other end of "Software Updater". Having done nothing on my part, other than moving to 23.04, the condition no longer presents itself. Grateful for your response, all the same.

Answer (score 2):

### What's the problem?

[image: Software Updater]

The message "Check your Internet connection." is unhelpful. The application can (and does) check your Internet connection and, obviously, (since the update ultimately works) your Internet connection is fine. **This message is a low-effort way of saying that they ran into some, unspecified, problem reading from *one or more of* the configured repositories**. But, as you've seen, *it does not necessarily mean that the download failed completely.*

Using other tools, such as the 'Synaptic' graphical package management tool (available in 'Software Boutique') you can get more information. For example, with Synaptic, I currently get the following response when attempting a 'Reload' (*Note: A similar, but less descriptive, message is available when updating from Software Boutique itself*):

[image: synaptic]

So it seems that my system (Ubuntu MATE 22.04) has a reference to archives from the [now-defunct](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422585/upgrade-to-22-04-from-21-10-impish-eol-release-no-longer-has-a-release-file) `[21.10]` 'impish' release. But even the above message confounds the problem since it's saying "does not have a release file" when, in fact, that repository *does not exist at all* (due to [rollout of the EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/)).

The 'Software & Updates' dialog (accessible by clicking 'Settings...' in the Software Updater) is where repository locations are configured. In my example, this includes the configured reference to the defunct 'impish-security' distribution at http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu. [*It's interesting that this isn't using 'https'.*]

[image: Software & Updates]

### So what's the fix?

If your case is similar or analogous to my example, the quick fix is to disable the offending software source that is listed in the 'Other Software' tab (shown above). Once this is done, Software Updater will stop complaining about this.

Alternatively, if you happen to know of a new (and still secure) location of the repository, you could change the URI (and/or Distribution) to specify that.

### What are the risks?

Disabling software sources prevents any associated security patches from being applied, so this should be done with an awareness of why the sources were present in the first place. Ideally, if you are deleting a software source, you would also uninstall any packages that it provides.

In my case, for now, I don't know why there is a source called **"Important security updates"** that points to an older version of Ubuntu. Maybe it was added by some component that I installed from a third-party but, without retracing my steps, it's hard to know. What I do know is that this source is no longer providing those "Important security updates", so ... oops.

Comment: just getting your responses today. Am still non-skilled user and rely on the expertise which establishes default settings. The "Failed to download..." issue no longer presents since I moved to 23.04. Another issue has also been less of an issue since 23.04. ty

Comment: Over the years, a lot of people have been told: ["Check your Internet connection."](https://askubuntu.com/q/141512/11522)